# I can't fully understand this assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Here is the assembly code of main:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x20,%rsp
mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
add    $0x8,%rax
mov    (%rax),%rax
mov    %rax,%rdi
callq  0x510 <atoi@plt>
mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
mov    %edx,%esi
mov    %eax,%edi
callq  0x63a <sub>
leaveq 
retq
```

And here is the C corresponding code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int sub(int x, int y){
        return 2*x+y;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
        int a;
        a = atoi(argv[1]);
        return sub(argc,a);
}
```

I believe it is allocating 20 bits in the stack, then it's pushing the values of the parameters from right to left into rbp - 14 and rbp - 20, am i right? Why it need to be 20 bits? and why 0x8 is added to rax?

Comment: it's impossible to allocate anything bitwise. It's just subtracting 0x20 here. this is an operation on pointers, so this is 32 bytes. That might be considered as the space for local variables. Cant't tell you why it's 32bytes, but maybe it helps a little.

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization. It's not normally useful trying to figure out details of unoptimized code. Normally it would be 16 bytes due to alignment or 8 bytes if frame pointer is omitted. The `0x8` is because you referenced `argv[1]` and a pointer is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an annotated version:
    / establish a stack frame.  Stacks must be aligned to conform with the ABI,
    / so despite only 2 (*8 = 16) locations being necessary, 4 8-byte (=32)
    / locations are reserved.
        push   %rbp
        mov    %rsp,%rbp
        sub    $0x20,%rsp

```
/ store away argc, argv for later.
    mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
/ get the value of argv[1]:  argv is a vector of char *, so
/ load argv:
    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
/ index by 1:
    add    $0x8,%rax
/ load argv[1].
    mov    (%rax),%rax
/ copy into first parameter of atoi
    mov    %rax,%rdi
    callq  0x510 <atoi@plt>
/ store the result
    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
/ load parameter 2 of sub:
    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
/ load parameter 1 of sub (argc).
    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
/ move parameters to abi parameter registers
    mov    %edx,%esi
    mov    %eax,%edi
    callq  0x63a <sub>
/ remove stack frame for this function
    leaveq 
    retq
```

This version removes the redundant load, stores for clarity:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x20,%rsp
mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
mov    8(%rsi), %rdi
callq  0x510 <atoi@plt>
mov    %eax, %rsi
mov    -0x14(%rbp), %rdi
callq  0x63a <sub>
leaveq 
retq
```

Comment: Your explanation made things very clear, thank you.

Comment: Except for the fact that the alignment requirement is 16 bytes so the extra 16 bytes are not needed. They are just a consequence of unoptimized code. Even your version can be reduced further by removing the frame pointer and using tail call optimization.